# Phpmyadmin page not found in laravel/homestead installation

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, vagrant, homestead

I have recently setup a homestead VM machine and am now trying to connect to a phpmyadmin to run a migrate command. However : 
1) when I go to 'mylaravelproject.test/phpmyadmin I get 'page not found, yet when I visit phpmyadmin.test on my machine, I can log into the databases.
2) the migrate scripts errors with a "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error.

I figure the two issues are connected and that somewhere my routing may be off but I have tried all different combinations. 
For clarity; I installed phpmyadmin by downloading and extracting the directory to my code base (/vagrant/code/phpmyadmin)

I have the below in my homestead.yaml file:
          - map: phpmyadmin.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/phpmyadmin
my host file features - 192.168.10.10 phpmyadmin.test
I have provisioned vagrant using 'vagrant provision' command

Can anyone help me connect accurately?

Comment: what's you database configuration in .env file ? and logint to homestead ssh and type mysql and see whether command is exist

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface that allows users and administrators to interact with a MySQL/MariaDB database. It doesn't expose any API or scripting interface to other programs, so you can't connect to it from your program or migrate command. You may intend to connect to MySQL instead.